# Какой именно язык исползует БД visual studio

Tags: sql, база-данных, visual-studio, ide

Например есть MSSQL,MySQL,SQLite и тд. У них всех немного отличается синтаксис. Так вот я хочу знать какой использует синтаксис локальная БД которую я создаю в Visual studio.

Comment: По умолчанию VS прописывает в настройках приложения app.config путь к MSSQL Express Edition, который поставляется вместе с VS.

Answer (score 1):

- Синтаксис запросов к локальной БД зависит от СУБД, используемой в
  проекте
- С Visual Studio нативно интегрируется (*поставляется "из
  коробки"*) СУБД [SQL
  Server](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)
- Язык, используемый в SQL Server -
  [T-SQL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL), подмножество
  языков семейства SQL